# Number of real solution(s) of $x$ for $e^x\cot x=1$

Tags: calculus

> Number of real solution(s) of  $x$ for $e^x\cot x=1$ where $x\in (0,2\pi)$ is______.

My approach is as follow.

I checked the graph and I separated the two function $y=e^x$ & $y=\tan x$ and saw that they intersect at two points.

How do I solve it without using a graph?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Split into two intervals, $(0,\pi)$ and $(\pi,2\pi)$. What can you say about the derivative of this function in each interval? What is the limit of the function when $x$ approaches $0$, $\pi$ (both from above and below), and $2\pi$?

Comment: For @Andrei's tip it helps to count roots of $e^{-x}-\cot x$ based on this continuous function's sign.